# Ambiguous behaviour of async function in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

**first version of code :**

```js
console.log("before function")
function changecolor(color) {
  return new Promise((reslove, request) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
      reslove("success")
    }, 2000)
  })
}
changecolor("red")
  .then(e => {
    console.log("changed successfully")
    console.log(e)
    return changecolor("green")
  }).then(e => {
    console.log("changed successfully")
    console.log(e)
    return changecolor("orange")
  }).then(e => {
    console.log("changed successfully")
    console.log(e)
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log("unsuccessful")
    console.log(e)
  })
console.log("last line")
```

**first version output :**

```
 before function
 last line
 changed successfully
 success
 changed successfully
 success
 changed successfully
 success
```

**second version of code :**

```js
console.log("before function")
async function changecolor(color) {
  console.log("inside function")
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
    console.log(`color is ${color}`)
    

  }, 2000)
  console.log("function end")
  return "success"
}
changecolor("red")
  .then(e => {
    console.log("changed successfully")
    console.log(e)
    return changecolor("green")
  }).then(e => {
    console.log("changed successfully")
    console.log(e)
    return changecolor("orange")
  }).then(e => {
    console.log("changed successfully")
    console.log(e)
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log("unsuccessful")
    console.log(e)
  })
console.log("last line")
```

**second version output :**

```
 before function
 inside function
 function end
 last line
 changed successfully
 success
 inside function
 function end
 changed successfully
 success
 inside function
 function end
 changed successfully
 success
 color is red
 color is green
 color is orange
```

**my problem :** when I run first version of code then the color of my html page turns to different background colors after 2 seconds each but in second version of code it turns all the background colors simultaneous after 2 seconds

I know javascript is single threaded and it executes other parts of the code when we encounter the setTimeOut() function

even though the code is same in both of them one uses pure promises and other uses async keyword but the output is different in both of them even when I use await keyword before setTimeOut() function in second version of code

I am new to javascript could anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions exist to simplify working with promises, but they won't automatically wait for anything. If you `await` a promise, then the function will pause, wait for that promise to resolve, and then resume. If you never `await` a promise, then your `async` function will run all the way to completion right away, at which point it returns. The return value is a promise, but since you havn't waited for anything, that promise resolves right away.

In other words, solution #2 isn't waiting for anything. It immediately calls changeColor, sets up a timout, then it immediately<sup>1</sup> goes into the `.then` where it calls changeColor again. You end up setting up a bunch of timeouts right at the start, then 2 seconds later they all go off.

If you want to use setTimeout as a promise, you will need to wrap it in a promise, like you did in your first example.

<sup>1) this happens as a microtask, so not quite synchronous</sup>

Comment: I have edited my code as below for second version:

Comment: async function getTimer(color){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        document.body.style.backgroundColor=color
        console.log("color is "+color)
        return "success"
},4000)
}


async function changecolor(color){
        console.log("inside function")
        await getTimer(color)
        console.log("function end")
        return "success"
}

Comment: still the colors change at a time

Comment: If you want to await a setTimeout, you need to wrap it in `new Promise`, like in your first example. And if you've moved it into a separate getTimer function, make sure to return the promise that you create.

Comment: ok now I understood the concept of `async` and `await` so they are a replacement for .then() calls, not for new Promise  thanks for your help